# Maintaining List of strings in app.config

Tags: c#-3.0

I would like to maintain a list of strings in app.config:
Eg:

```
   <ResourceTypes>
    <Resource>Crusher</Resource>
    <Resource>Berth</Resource>
    <Resource>OBP</Resource>
   </ResourceTypes>
```

And later use this list to populate combobox on a winform.

How to read this from app.config (c#).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class.