# namespaces in application settings

Tags: .net

I am migrating an old application to a newer .NET-version. The current application stores arrays with user settings into the registry.

In the new application I want to change this mechanism into .NET Application settings (app.config), but I have only figured out so far how to store one-dimensional values in there, for example...

```
My.Settings.myName1 = "John Doe"
My.Settings.myMail1 = "john.doe@somemaildomain.com"
My.Settings.myName2 = "Lorem Ipsum"
My.Settings.myMail2 = "lorem.ipsum@somemaildomain.com"
```

I guess it is possible somehow to work not only with single values, but with arrays, too, which ideally could be accessed by a namespace, something like this:

```
REM just demo code to display what i want, no idea if something like this works...
My.Settings.myContacts(1).Name = "John Doe"
My.Settings.myContacts(1).Mail = "john.doe@somemaildomain.com"
My.Settings.myContacts(2).Name = "Lorem Ipsum"
My.Settings.myContacts(2).Mail = "lorem.ipsum@somemaildomain.com"
```

Is something similar possible? If not, is there another way how to work with multidimensional values / arrays in the .NET Application settings?

Comment: Check this Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025168/maintaining-list-of-strings-in-app-config, in short create a custom configuration section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET app settings are key, value pair only.

If you want multidimensional values in app.config you should look at implementing your own custom config section.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx